# JQuery Template loop count

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Having had JQuery template plugin recommended to me to use, I was wondering how to make a counter so inside the script 'name_tmpl' it would only loop through and display the names 4 times rather than display every single one from the JSON file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "url.com",
    success: showAllNames
});


function showAllNames(responseData) {
        $("#name_tmpl").tmpl(responseData.games).appendTo("#names-holder");  
}


<script id="name_tmpl" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">  
    <p>${name}</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each function inside the template, something like this:

```
<script id="name_tmpl" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">  
{{each(i, name) names}}
 {{if i<4}}
  <p>${name}</p>
 {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

And call it as :

```
function showAllNames(responseData) {
        $("#name_tmpl").tmpl({"names":responseData.names}).appendTo("#names-holder");  
}
```